# Accidentally deleted my own question

Tags: support, deleted-questions

I've accidentally deleted my own [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88945/hotkeys-stop-working-in-eclipse), should I ask it again or can it be undeleted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've just undeleted it for you. :)

Comment: thanks for the help =)